# C# Web API Error 404 on POST

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I am getting an error 404 when I try and so a post on my web api and i'm not sure why i'm getting it the url and everything are correct.

```
http://10.0.1.96/testwebapi/api/case/UpdateCasePersonal/?id=4584&forename=Andy&surname=Wilson&email=example@example.co.uk&telephone=0166%20254%204876&mobile=0733333333&title=Mr
```

That is my Url to the web api code that I will put next

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("updatecasepersonal/")]
public string UpdateCasePersonal(string Caseid, string Title, string Forename, string Surname, string Telephone, string Email, string Mobile)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        var query = $@"UPDATE TestDB.dbo.[crm-data] SET Title=" + Title + ", Forename=" + Forename + ", Surname=" + Surname + ", Telephone=" + Telephone + ", Email=" + Email + ", Mobile=" + Mobile + " WHERE Caseid=" + Caseid;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            var dtb = new DataTable();
            var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dtb);
            return "Done";
        }
    }
}
```

also I am doing it right trying to update my table like that? or have I done everything wrong as i'm not fluent in c# yet

can provide more code if needed

This is my code that calls the api

```
onUpdateClick(e) {
    this.setState({
        updatedForename: this.state.Case.Forename,
        updatedSurname: this.state.Case.Surname,
        updatedHomeTelephone: this.state.Case.Telephone,
        updatedMobileTelephone: this.state.Case.Mobile,
        updatedEmail: this.state.Case.Email,
        updatedTitle: this.state.titleValue,
        updatedPurpose: this.state.purposeValue,
        updatedMaritalStatus: this.state.maritalValue,
        updatedEmpStatus: this.state.empValue,
    }, function () {

        var id = this.state.Case.Caseid;
        var forename = this.state.updatedForename;
        var surname = this.state.updatedSurname;
        var email = this.state.updatedEmail;
        var homeTelephone = this.state.updatedHomeTelephone;
        var mobileTelephone = this.state.updatedMobileTelephone;
        var title = this.state.updatedTitle;

        axios.post('http://10.0.1.96/testwebapi/api/case/UpdateCasePersonal/', {
            params: {
                id: id,
                forename: forename,
                surname: surname,
                email: email,
                telephone: homeTelephone,
                mobile: mobileTelephone,
                title: title
            }
        }).then(function (res) {
        }).catch(function (err) {
        });

    });
    this.setState({
        hasSaved: true
    });

}
```

Comment: Your established `Route` is not the same as the url you're posting to. You're `Route` is simply `updatecasepersonal`. None of that extra stuff afterwards. If you want to pass all those values as parameters to the call, you need to send it as data. Not concatenated in the url. So you should be sending the Post request to `http://10.0.1.96/testwebapi/api/case/updatecasepersonal`

Comment: As an aside, never concatenate a SQL statement string with user input. Use parameters instead. See http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Comment: @JunKang or just remove the `Route` attribute and fix the parameter name

Comment: can someone write an answer with some example code please

Comment: I'm just guessing but perhaps the / after UpdateCasePersonal could be the issue?

Comment: @Simon I removed the / it now says post but then i get No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. yes i have cors enabled because its enabled for the rest

Comment: @JunKang How do I pass in parameters instead and how would I write the C# to accept them as I'm not good with C#

Comment: Two issues: 1) your route has a trailing slash and is all lower case, while your request is camel-cased.  2) Your query string should be passed in the message body (it's a Post after all) instead of the URL.

Comment: @afeygin how do i pass it in the message body also urls arent case sensitive or are they now?

Comment: "Users should always consider that URLs are case-sensitive" (https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to send the concatenated data in the URL, do something like this:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("updatecasepersonal/{Caseid}/{Title}/{Forename}/{Surname}/{Email}/{Telephone}/{Mobile}")]
public string UpdateCasePersonal(string Caseid, string Title, string Forename, string Surname, string Telephone, string Email, string Mobile)
{
    ...
}
```

And your url should simply look like :

```
http://10.0.1.96/testwebapi/api/case/UpdateCasePersonal/4584/Mr/Andy/Wilson/example@example.co.uk/0166%20254%204876/0733333333/
```

## This is not good practice.

This completely exposes your data in the request. In general, concatenation is almost never the best way to do anything related to data. You SHOULD send the data as a whole to the call instead. Something like:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("updatecasepersonal/{CaseId}"]
public string UpdateCasePersonal(string Caseid, RequestDto request)
{
    ...
}
```

Of course, `RequestDto` should be a class you make that requires all those fields: Title, Forename, Surname, Email, etc, and pass it in your Javascript (or wherever your sending the post from). And it should be named something apt to your request. Like since this looks like user profile data, or something along those lines, something like `ContactDto`.

Comment: could you give me more of a code example, also you dont have to worry about exposing data that much as its an internal system. plus the people who use it dont even know how to open the dev tools window most likley

Comment: im now getting an internal server error 500 and when i put debug mode on and type the url out with some data it gives me this error `The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.`

Comment: I'm not familiar with axios, so I can't provide more examples for the sending of the request from your Javascript. The examples I provided should be enough to answer your original quesiton, and set you on the right path of solving the original issue. `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` is a Cors issue, and an entirely different problem.

Comment: yeah i know i fixed the cors thing by repeating the enable cors code able the first post but now I get the error in my above comment. plus reason im asking here is they are all connected issues and id have to wait 90 mins to post my next question

Comment: `The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'` The issue there is pretty clear... Your javascript is sending a get request instead of a post when your endpoint is clearly marked with `[HttpPost]`

Comment: I can see that in your javascript, it says post. But the error your getting isn't somehow just lying to you. For whatever reason, that I can't really help debug without looking directly at your code, is getting a `Get` request rather than a post.

Comment: If you're really not concerned about exposing your data, you can always set everything back to the way it was before, and try implementing the fix I recommended (that isn't best practice) and simply concatenate the url.

Comment: `axios.post('http://10.0.1.96/testwebapi/api/case/UpdateCasePersonal/' + id + '/' + title + '/' + forename ....)` As long as you make sure the url is concatenated in the correct order. Since the data is sent through the url, you don't need to send params or a body.